# Averaging Dynamic Vlookups in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to make an automatically calculating spreadsheet for tracking tournament statistics. Players earn 3 points for each win they receive and 1 point for each draw. Here is what my sheet of data looks like currently:

Column 1: Player Alias
Columns 2-6: Player Opponents
Columns 7-11: Match Results vs Opponents (Opponent in C2, Match Result in C7, Opponent in C3, Match Result in C8, C4/C9, C5/C10, C6/C11)
Column 12: Match Points Earned (`COUNTIF(RC7:RC11,">.5")*3 + COUNTIF(RC7:RC11,"=.5")`)
Column 13: Match Win Percentage (`C12 / (COUNTA(RC7:RC11)*3)`)
Column 14: Opponents' Match Win Percentage (`AVERAGE(VLOOKUP(RC2,C1:C13,13,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC3,C1:C13,13,FALSE),...,...,...`)

What I want to do is be able to dynamically add opponents and match results (expand range 2-6 and 7-11 respectively) and have columns 12-14 update without needing to add new VLOOKUP arguments to the average.

Is it possible to get the average of a variable number of VLOOKUP results?

Comment: Not with your current design... If I were to design this I probably would need to make an "Opponents" sheet that only lists the different opponents.  Probably a "Match Results" sheet where you have a formula that dynamically takes all the opponents and makes a super long row of each opponent vs opponent (so the number of opponents^2 long).  Then it would be easy on another sheet like "Match Points" to summarize the match points, the win percentage, and your opponents win percentage...but that 2nd sheet would be a lot of work....That is if you want a variable number of opponents